# Black screen on lineageos 17.1 RPI4

Tags: pi-4

recently I have installed lineageos 17.1 on my rpi4 with pinn (noobs if you prefer) and when I try to start lineage, it show a black screen and I tried to put 640p*480p and nothing, always black screen. Please help me I've tried everything I saw and nothing work

Comment: `I tried to put 640p*480p` ... what does that mean? ...... `I've tried everything I saw` ... what did you try?

Comment: maybe the screen is not powered on

Comment: In some forums I saw someone who put 640*480 and it work for him and "everything I saw" it's to mean I try and try "solutions" on internet and it doesn't work
and the screen is always active because it turn on when I turn on the rpi

Comment: if you will not say what you tried, then people will not waste their time giving you solutions because you probably already tried those solutions

Comment: Oh ok sorry. I've tried to change resolution.txt but it didn't work, I've tried to change SwiftShader to messa but I can't access to the terminal because it show a black screen and I've tried other version of lineageos like 18 or 19 but only lineage 16 work but I can't install gapps on it so it can't be usable (for me) (and I try to use the smaller gapps package and didn't work)

Comment: and I forgot to say my screen is a 7" touchscreen for rpi4